# When does jenkins read config.xml?

Tags: hudson, jenkins

We want to swap in changes and would like to avoid having to restart Jenkins.  The changes we need to make aren't well suited for parameterized builds.

Related question: if the change isn't automatically detected or at least reread when the build is triggered, is there a way to force the file to be reread without a process restart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you mean the config.xml for a build job:

If you edit the job configuration via the Jenkins UI the updates will be applied as soon as the job is built again.

If you edit it directly on the file system you'll need to use the Jenkins CLI or a direct POST request.

Comment: yes. your are absolutely right. More here https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI

Comment: When I am upgrading jenkins to latest version 1.631 but its showing in Jenkins UI,  But when i am checking config.xml file the version still shows old number. Can any one please suggest me how can we update config.xml as with Jenkins UI